# Possible letter combinations of a dial pad in linear time using a recursive approach

Tags: javascript, array, recursion, complexity, set

Time complexity: I walk the initial unzipped array of keys representing the number O(N) backwards. I then do an inner walk of the proceeding array of letters *O(L^2), mapping it to every value in the target O(T)). finally, I  flattening the values and repeat to get O(N^3)

I know this can not be solved in linear time, but can the runtime be improved (maybe recursively) and is my time analysis correct?

```js
let letters_keys = {
  2: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  3: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  4: ['g', 'h', 'i'],
  5: ['j', 'k', 'l'],
  6: ['m', 'n', 'o'],
  7: ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'],
  8: ['t', 'u', 'v'],
  9: ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
}

function all_possable(num) {
  return num.toString().split('').map(x => new Set(letters_keys[x]))
}

function remp(possable) {
  possable = all_possable(possable)
  possable = possable.map(x => [...x])

  let v = possable.reduceRight((x, a) => {

    if (x.length === 0) {
      x = a
    } else {

     let k = x.map(c => a.map(b => b + c))
      x = k.reduce((acc, a) => acc.concat(a), [])
    }
    return x
  }, [])
  return v.sort()

}

console.log(remp(5678).sort())
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your purpose in writing this code?

If the entire task is enumerate the combinations, it's not possible to do less work than going through all combinations. An \$ n \$ digit number will have between \$ 3^n \$ and \$ 4^n \$ possible combinations, depending on how many of those digits are 7s and 9s.

On the other hand, additional knowledge about the purpose of the function could guide the search for something more useful. For example, I imagine this function might then be the input to a filter which narrows them down it to dictionary words. In that case, you could preemptively stop searching if there are no words in the dictionary that start with a given prefix. (The [trie data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is a classic option for keeping track of this sort of thing.)

---

Assorted other comments on the code

- Because what you are passing is fundamentally a sequence of keypresses rather than a number per se, consider having `remp` take a string instead of a number.
- `Set` is probably unnecessary expense and complexity if all you want is to enumerate a few characters. Whatever data type you use, consider sharing an object for all usages of a given digit's letters.
- `all_possable` isn't a particularly descriptive name for that function. I also have no idea what `remp` means.
- Although it doesn't affect the code, the correct spelling is possible.